# Understanding Javascript D3 visualization quadtree

Tags: d3.js, javascript, force-layout, quadtree

I am trying to use and understand the [D3 visualization library](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) (http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), and I am looking at [their force directed code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.layout.js#L233) and it seems they are using a quadtree to calculate the force on a particle. The code is

```
      var k = kc * quad.count * dn * dn;
      node.px -= dx * k;
      node.py -= dy * k;
```

where it seems thay quad.count is the number of particles in the quadtree node. But looking at their [quadtree code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.geom.js#L696) in https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.geom.js#L696, I can't find any reference to `count`, and how it is being calculated. I ask because I want to modify some things to perhaps change the "weight" or "charge" of each node.

Comment: Links don't work anymore, @highBandWidth. And what was your experience qith quadtree in d3.js, since this question? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `d3_layout_forceAccumulate` method:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js#L294-324

The quadtree by itself doesn't compute the center of charge for its particles (because the quadtree only knows about particle positions, and doesn’t make any assumptions about their charges). After the quadtree is generated, the force layout recursively computes the center of charge for each quadrant.

Comment: Thanks, got it! Perhaps the method ought to be called something like `d3_layout_quadCenterAccumulate`, since it is not really accumulating forces, just calculating `cx`, `cy`, and `count`.

Comment: Private globals in D3 are scoped by their associated class, to avoid potential name collisions. So anything defined in src/layout/force should have the prefix d3_layout_force.

Comment: ohh the force is just a prefix for the function Accumulate.