# Understanding d3 visualization quadtree, continued (2)

Tags: d3.js, quadtree

For the [collision detection example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298) and other quadtree applications, how does d3 update the quadtree used inside the "tick" timer callback? E.g. is the quadtree always recomputed "from scratch" inside

```
force.on("tick", function(e) {
  var q = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
      i = 0,
      n = nodes.length;
...
```

each time the positions of the data-bound objects stored in the "data" array changes, or is it updating the previous quadtree in some more efficient manner?

This question is related to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419893/understanding-javascript-d3-visualization-quadtree) that has already been answered. Also the link

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.geom.js#L696

on the previous question's page seems broken now and not sure how to fix this myself.

Sorry about the confusion, any help is appreciated!

Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you've linked to, the quadtree is recomputed from scratch on each tick. It doesn't save the tree for the next iteration once computed.

Comment: that's interesting, thanks! i wonder if updating based on the previous state could provide significant performance improvement in some cases? If so, should this become an "issue" on the d3 github page?

Comment: In general, the drawing and animation of the circles (or elements in general) is going to be more expensive than this computation. But yes, there may well be cases where it turns out to be the limiting factor. You could certainly open an issue for this, but it would be low priority unless you have a specific case where it causes a problem. The other question is how much could be gained through incrementality -- it may not be that much.

Comment: that makes sense, if and when i get more detailed/quantitative information about the savings then i will revisit this question. thanks